# How can I disable large size warnings in JupyterLab?

Tags: file-upload, warnings, jupyter-lab, large-files

Example of a large size warning in JupyterLab:

[image]

I don't want to disable all warning, but only large size warnings.

Comment: I don't think this is currently possible. The value is hard-coded, but it could be made configurable if someone wants to contribute. Relevant lines are linked in related but distinct issue https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/5413

Answer (score -1):

While running the notebook you can try the below command:

`jupyter notebook -W ignore`

Also below is the command to restart the warnings

`jupyter notebook -W default`

**OR**
You can also use the warnings package

`import warnings`
`warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')`

This should work and you should be able to ignore all the warning for the whole notebook
Thank you